# Java create strings from Buffered Reader and compare Strings

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am using Java + Selenium 1 to test a web application.

I have to read through a text file line by line using befferedreader.readLine and compare the data that was found to another String.

Is there way to assign each line a unique string? I think it would be something like this:

```
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:\\write.txt");
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

    String strLine;
    String[] strArray = null;
    int p=0;
        // Read File Line By Line

    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        strArray[p] = strLine;
        assertTrue(strArray[p].equals(someString));
        p=p+1;
    }
```

Comment: you actually don't need the string array at all, unless you are planning to do something with it later. Just use the strLine variable you already created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try something like:

```
public final static String someString = "someString";

public boolean isMyFileOk(String filename){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(filename);
    boolean fileOk = true;
    while(sc.hasNext() && fileOk){
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        fileOk = isMyLineOk(line);
    }
    sc.close();
    return fileOk;
}

public boolean isMyLineOk(String line){
    return line.equals(someString);
}
```

The [Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class is usually a great class to read files :)

And as suggested, you may check one line at a time instead of loading them all in memory before processing them. This may not be an issue if your file is relatively small but you better keep your code scalable, especially for doing the exact same thing :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this is that you don't know how many lines there are, so you can't size your array correctly. Use a `List<String>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In order of decreasing importance,

- You don't need to store the `String`s in an array at all, as pointed out by Perception.
- You don't know how many lines there are, so as pointed out by Qwerky, if you do need to store them you should use a resizeable collection like `ArrayList`.
- `DataInputStream` is not needed: you can just wrap your `FileInputStream` directly in an `InputStreamReader`.